# Get text from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array which has button elements in a certain order.

```
var arr = [ $('.buttons')[0], $('.buttons')[2], $('.buttons')[1], $('.buttons')[4] ];
```

How do I get the text of each button? Below is what I tried.

```
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
      var butText = value.text();
      //do something...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery object `$(this)` to get button text.

```js
var arr = [$('.buttons')[0], $('.buttons')[2], $('.buttons')[1], $('.buttons')[4]];

$.each(arr, function () {
    var butText = $(this).text();
    console.log(butText)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="buttons">button 0</button>
<button class="buttons">button 1</button>
<button class="buttons">button 2</button>
<button class="buttons">button 3</button>
<button class="buttons">button 4</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to retrieve each of them in the specified order, you could just consider looping through them, using `$(this)` to refer to each element in the iteration :

```
// Iterate through each element
$.each(arr, function(){
      // Get the text (this will refer to each of your elements)
      var buttonText = $(this).text();
      // Do something here
});
```

**Complete Example**

```js
var arr = [ $('.buttons')[0], $('.buttons')[2], $('.buttons')[1], $('.buttons')[4] ];
$.each(arr,function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='buttons'>A</button>
<button class='buttons'>B</button>
<button class='buttons'>C</button>
<button class='buttons'>D</button>
<button class='buttons'>E</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the text of those elements to a new array without `$.each()` looping, you can use use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```
var arr = [ $('.buttons')[0], $('.buttons')[2], $('.buttons')[1], $('.buttons')[4] ];
var texts = arr.map(function(a) {return a.text();});
```

which will return an array equivalent to

```
[ $('.buttons')[0].text(), $('.buttons')[2].text(), $('.buttons')[1].text(), $('.buttons')[4].text() ]
```